# Running mass mail functionality in background

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I am using mass mailer functionality using zend in my site, currently i am using cron job for sending mail in background but it occupies some space in server and its unnecessarily running every 3 min

**My Doubt is:**

1) Is there any possibility run the cron only mail send button click

2) Is there any other way to over come this problem

Comment: You can set time to run code in specified time period in your cron settings of the server. Also, other solutions might require more details like what sort of mail it sends, is it for newsletter or other?

Comment: Hai smith , we set cron time period for every 3 min, if we send mail or not every 3 min the cron is running and log file created, we using mass mail for newsletter

Comment: well then set it to run once a day. Its not likely that you send many newsletter per day. Also, you can send newsletter manually once you create a newsletter. Like when newsletter contents are created and saved, send mail the same time after the newsletter is created. Optionally you can create a interface where you select a newsletter to send, and upon clicking send button, this newsletter is send to all subscribed users.

Comment: Thanks Smith , We are using same functionality in Recruit Process, In that people may send 1000 mail at a time, the mail should automatically deliver to recipients,